# Click on a specific time of fullcalendar plugin

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have this code that helps me to get a date that I already click on it with `fullcalendar` plugin:

```
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

      if (allDay) {
        // Clicked on the entire day
        $('#calendar')
            .fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay'/* or 'basicDay' */)
            .fullCalendar('gotoDate',
                date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
                console.log($(this).data("date"));
        }
      },
```

This script takes me to a `fullDay` hour display:

[image]

But how can I get the time now. Getting the time and the date will help me afterwards to make a popup window to make an appointment. But for now how can I click on the time of this specific day too.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood it well. Do you wanna fire a popup after clicking on a specific date range?

Comment: I want to fire `title = prompt('Event Title:');` on a time not on a date

Comment: Yeah, but a "time" is a "datetime", so I think you should use the `dayClick` event too, and format the date so you only get the time.

Comment: BTW, if you wanna prompt something related to an event, use `eventClick` event instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing from the comments... I asked what exactly do you wanna do, and you answered that "you want to fire an event title prompt on click".

If you wanna get the info from an event, use the [`eventClick` event](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/).

If you wanna get info from a specific date/time range, use [`dayClick` event](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/).

Both events return the datetime object, so you can easily extract the info from the event / date.

**Edit: [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/93auhxdw/)**

Comment: nope. I need to click on a time now. I already clicked on a date, now I need to choose a time

Comment: Come on! So you don't understand the documentation nor my comments and you downvote me? thanks dude!

Comment: Please, check out the edit.. I've added a working example.

Comment: First of all, I do never downvote who post answers on my questions. Second of all, yes, it works. Thanks Sir That's it.

Comment: sorry was a confusion on the moment.. saw the downvote and the comment at the same time :_D